# Synchronising a collection over a websocket connection

Tags: c#, .net, xsockets.net

I'm working on a client-server system at the moment, and I'm trying to get a collection to synchronise across a websocket. Everything is in C# + .Net 4.5, and I was wondering if there was a particular best practise for synchronising data over a websocket. It's a one way sync:

Server: BindingCollection< MyClass >   ----- Websocket ----->   Client: BindingCollection< MyClass >

The collection could be up to 1000 objects with 20 fields each so sending the whole lot each time seems a little wasteful.

Comment: Do you want to send the changes to the clients when the server side collection changes?

Comment: @Uffe Yes that's the idea, just a one way sync.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a observer pattern and only send the changed object to be synced.

So I finally took the time to write a small example.
I am using a in-memory generic repository that invokes events on changes. The changes is then sent to all clients so that you do not have to send the complete list/collection.

#### A simple model to monitor

```
using System;

namespace SynchronizingCollection.Common.Model
{
    public class MyModel
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
}
```

#### A Generic Repository

Notice the event OnChange that is called when something is added/updated/removed. The event is "subscribed" to in a XSockets long running controller (a singleton) See the "RepoMonitor" class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace SynchronizingCollection.Server.Repository
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A static generic thread-safe repository for in-memory storage
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TK">Key Type</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Value Type</typeparam>
    public static class Repository<TK, T>
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// When something changes
        /// </summary>
        public static event EventHandler<OnChangedArgs<TK,T>> OnChange;

        private static ConcurrentDictionary<TK, T> Container { get; set; }

        static Repository()
        {
            Container = new ConcurrentDictionary<TK, T>();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Adds or updates the entity T with key TK
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="key"></param>
        /// <param name="entity"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static T AddOrUpdate(TK key, T entity)
        {
            var obj = Container.AddOrUpdate(key, entity, (s, o) => entity);
            if(OnChange != null)
                OnChange.Invoke(null,new OnChangedArgs<TK, T>(){Key = key,Value = entity, Operation =  Operation.AddUpdate});
            return obj;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Removes the entity T with key TK
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="key"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static bool Remove(TK key)
        {
            T entity;
            var result = Container.TryRemove(key, out entity);
            if (result)
            {
                if (OnChange != null)
                    OnChange.Invoke(null, new OnChangedArgs<TK, T>() { Key = key, Value = entity, Operation = Operation.Remove});
            }
            return result;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Removes all entities matching the expression f
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="f"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static int Remove(Func<T, bool> f)
        {
            return FindWithKeys(f).Count(o => Remove(o.Key));
        }        

        /// <summary>
        /// Find all entities T matching the expression f
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="f"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static IEnumerable<T> Find(Func<T, bool> f)
        {
            return Container.Values.Where(f);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Find all entities T matching the expression f and returns a Dictionary TK,T
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="f"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static IDictionary<TK, T> FindWithKeys(Func<T, bool> f)
        {
            var y = from x in Container
                    where f.Invoke(x.Value)
                    select x;
            return y.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns all entities as a Dictionary TK,T
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static IDictionary<TK, T> GetAllWithKeys()
        {
            return Container;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns all entities T from the repository
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
        {
            return Container.Values;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get a single entity T with the key TK
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="key"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static T GetById(TK key)
        {
            return Container.ContainsKey(key) ? Container[key] : default(T);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get a single entity T as a KeyValuePair TK,T with the key TK
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="key"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static KeyValuePair<TK, T> GetByIdWithKey(TK key)
        {
            return Container.ContainsKey(key) ? new KeyValuePair<TK, T>(key, Container[key]) : new KeyValuePair<TK, T>(key, default(T));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Checks if the repository has a key TK
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="key"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static bool ContainsKey(TK key)
        {
            return Container.ContainsKey(key);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Event argument and an enum to know what change just happend

```
using System;

namespace SynchronizingCollection.Server.Repository
{
    /// <summary>
    /// To send changes in the repo
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TK"></typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    public class OnChangedArgs<TK,T> : EventArgs
    {
        public Operation Operation { get; set; }
        public TK Key { get; set; }
        public T Value { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace SynchronizingCollection.Server.Repository
{
    /// <summary>
    /// What kind of change was performed
    /// </summary>
    public enum Operation
    {
        AddUpdate,
        Remove
    }
}
```

#### The Controller that send changes to the clients...

```
using System;
using SynchronizingCollection.Common.Model;
using SynchronizingCollection.Server.Repository;
using XSockets.Core.XSocket;
using XSockets.Core.XSocket.Helpers;
using XSockets.Plugin.Framework;
using XSockets.Plugin.Framework.Attributes;

namespace SynchronizingCollection.Server
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Long running controller that will send information to clients about the collection changes
    /// </summary>
    [XSocketMetadata(PluginRange = PluginRange.Internal, PluginAlias = "RepoMonitor")]
    public class RepositoryMonitor : XSocketController
    {
        public RepositoryMonitor()
        {
            Repository<Guid, MyModel>.OnChange += RepositoryOnChanged;
        }

        private void RepositoryOnChanged(object sender, OnChangedArgs<Guid, MyModel> e)
        {
            switch (e.Operation)
            {
                case Operation.Remove:
                    this.InvokeTo<Demo>(p => p.SendUpdates, e.Value,"removed");
                break;                    
                case Operation.AddUpdate:
                    this.InvokeTo<Demo>(p => p.SendUpdates, e.Value, "addorupdated");
                break;                    
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

#### The XSockets controller that clients call to add/remove/update the collection.

```
using System;
using SynchronizingCollection.Common.Model;
using SynchronizingCollection.Server.Repository;
using XSockets.Core.XSocket;

namespace SynchronizingCollection.Server
{
    public class Demo : XSocketController
    {
        public bool SendUpdates { get; set; }

        public Demo()
        {
            //By default all clients get updates
            SendUpdates = true;
        }

        public void AddOrUpdateModel(MyModel model)
        {
            Repository<Guid, MyModel>.AddOrUpdate(model.Id, model);
        }

        public void RemoveModel(MyModel model)
        {
            Repository<Guid, MyModel>.Remove(model.Id);
        }        
    }
}
```

#### And a demo client in C# that adds and removed 10 different objects... But it would be easy to use the JavaScript API as well. Especially with knockoutjs for manipulating the collection on the client.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using SynchronizingCollection.Common.Model;
using XSockets.Client40;

namespace SynchronizingCollection.Client
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var c = new XSocketClient("ws://127.0.0.1:4502","http://localhost","demo");

            c.Controller("demo").OnOpen += (sender, connectArgs) => Console.WriteLine("Demo OPEN");

            c.Controller("demo").On<MyModel>("addorupdated", model => Console.WriteLine("Updated " + model.Name));
            c.Controller("demo").On<MyModel>("removed", model => Console.WriteLine("Removed " + model.Name));

            c.Open();

            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                var m = new MyModel() {Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Person Nr" + i, Age = i};
                c.Controller("demo").Invoke("AddOrUpdateModel", m);

                Thread.Sleep(2000);

                c.Controller("demo").Invoke("RemoveModel", m);
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

You can download the project from my dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5ljbedovx6ufkww/SynchronizingCollection.zip?dl=0

Regards
Uffe

Comment: Thanks for such an incredibly comprehensive answer! I'll upvote when I have enough rep to do so.